# Brightness, Screen Resolution, Graphics card issues with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, brightness

I'm new to ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I found a lot of problem in it after installation. Not a major problem, but i wish to rectify them.

**1. Brightness problem**:
I tried to change the brightness using keyboard hotkeys and the slider in the top of the screen. Both are not working. I tried to change grub by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`  but it does worked for me

**2.Screen Resolution**
: In the settings it doesnt show any options. The only option it shows is `1024x786(4:3)`. I'm using a 15.6" Laptop.I'm attaching a screenshot for reference [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RNK0.png)

**3.Graphics card**: I have Nvidia GeForce Gtx 1650Ti dedicated graphics card, also have istalled latest 450 driver [driver installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVcwZ.png),
[Graphics details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8QB.png). What my problem is when I use gazebo I can feel it is very slow while using like adding new world. So i checked the system details it shows [System Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCHVm.png) i tried different solution provided in internet nothing worked.

**NOTE: I'm using HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec1050AX**

Please provide me a solution to resolve these issues
you can reach me through my email `bupeshkam@gmail.com`

Comment: Is there something preventing you using the latest LTS version **(Ubuntu 20.04)**?

Comment: Yes for ROS project purpose I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04**